# Looping through array in PowerShell script to delete DFS targets

Tags: arrays, powershell, depth-first-search

I have the need to remove several DFS targets.  I have a CSV file that has the Path and TargetPath info and wrote a script to try and bring that into an array and loop through it to do this but am getting error:

> Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet.  You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Very new to scripting but successfully wrote a very similar script that loops through an array to create Windows shares that I used as an example for this one but seem to be missing something.

```
$TargetsToDelete = Import-Csv "DFS_Targets.csv"

foreach ($Array in $TargetsToDelete) {
    Remove-DfsnFolderTarget -Path "$Array.Path" -TargetPath  "$Array.TargetPath"
}
```

My .csv file looks like so:

```
Path,TargetPath
\\example.com\dfsfolder\example,\\servername\exampleshare
\\example.com\dfsfolder\example2,\\servername\exampleshare2
\\example.com\dfsfolder\example3,\\servername\exampleshare3
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes from inside your foreach loop

Comment: What Dave said. Your code doesn't work b/c PowerShell does not support index or dot-access operations on variables in strings. And putting quotes around the arguments isn't needed here anyway.

Comment: I tried removing the double quotes and got the same result/error.  I should have indicated in the original post, but I suspected that might be the issue and had already tried single, double, and no quotes around those variables and none made a difference.  Still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe `"$($Array.Path)"`